# Why is a little girl correct usage of "a little"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

A Little is expected to be used before an uncountable noun while few is used before plural nouns.

Then why is this correct:

> They have two little girls.

While this is incorrect:

> They have two few girls.

Comment: Because it’s not “a little” it’s “a girl” who happens to be little.

Comment: Comments self-deleted. This question should be closed for lack of research.

Comment: Because then it would be "too few girls" and mean something entirely different.

Answer (score 3):

The rule you mention applies to the phrase 'a little' meaning 'a small quantity of'. However, 'little' as an adjective describing 'girl' simply means 'small'.

Comment: If the OP is still unclear about what you mean the phrase could be changed to 'one little girl' without changing the meaning much. We would not normally say 'there was one little girl in the park' unless we wanted to emphasise something about the solitary nature of the little girl (perhaps 'there was one little girl in the park with lots of little boys') but if we say 'There was a little girl in the park' the word _a_ stands in place of _one_.